# What can I do if my professor says he won't let me publish my biology research?

Tags: publications, ethics, professorship

My professor firstly approved everything I've written, and now he is telling me the paper is unworthy and even contains plagiarism. His words also were 'I don't want to be a part of your failure so I won't approve it'. I don't know what could possibly go wrong and why he acts like this. Can you tell me what should I do?

Comment: You should listen to your professor, in particular if he is right about the paper containing plagiarism. He has no incentive to not let you succeed, when possible.

Comment: Well, did you plagiarize?

Comment: Have you asked him which parts of the paper are plagiarized?

Comment: Your only recourse is to ask your professor what you can do to improve the paper enough that it's worth publishing, whether that means rewriting or also doing additional research. Either way, you need to get a clear answer from him.

Comment: "I don't know what could possibly go wrong and why he acts like this." - I smell a troll.

Comment: I know it is weird, definitely rare, but this might happen. As a postdoc, I had an idea and developed it over an weekend. When I went to show it to my supervisor, he shut me down, saying that was "absurd", "waste of time", etc... Since I did the whole thing solo, I went to another professor, explained the whole thing and we wrote an article about it. It didn't get accepted and I ended up publishing it as a techrep. I could revise it (I wrote the code in the weekend and finished writing on wednesday, deadline on friday), but I was so disheartened that I never bothered...

Comment: I trust the professor. You have most likely copied from someone else and therefore should not be allowed to publish.

Comment: The professor must approve your paper only if (s)he is a coauthor. If (s)he does not like your work, (s)he can withdraw his(her) name from the paper and give a carte-blanche to you. If your paper is a failure, this will be only your failure in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that sometimes people may just search for pretext and will give all shorts of excuses. However, before jumping to that conclusion you should ask yourself are you sure you are right? Most of the times professors will actually give proper advice within the limits of their own personality and human nature.

So to answer your question try to examine and verify that your work is up to the expectations of your supervisor.